# How To Access Sanity Desk

Tags: database, backend, content-management-system, sanity

I just finished my React app using sanity as the backend. I deployed the app and it's working fine but whenever I want to add data to the database I find myself accessing the database through the command:

> sanity start

and then adding my content. Is there an admin page so I can access the sanity database without needing to go back to the source code Or should I implement my own admin to send posting requests to the sanity database? I need a way to access the database after deployment so what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You can only access the sanity data locally.